# How to check if cookies exist in ColdFusion 2016?

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-2016

We just recently upgraded our test server from CF10 to CF16. One of the problems are cookies. After I tried to login to our system message showed on the screen `Cookies Are Not Enabled!`. I have checked the code and there is `cfif` that checks if `Cookie.test` is not defined. Here is example of my code:

```
<cfif NOT IsDefined("Cookie.test")>
    Cookies Are Not Enabled!
    <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

This is line of code where I found cookie.test:

```
<cfcookie name="test">
```

This is on the very bottom of the page and `isDefined()` is on the very top. So I'm wondering how this can be checked in ColdFusion 2016? Thank you.

Comment: How/Where is the code setting the `Cookie.test` value? Can you show us that code?

Comment: @Miguel-F I have found that line of code. It's defined on the very bottom of the page. I just want to give you heads up this is an old legacy code. I'm not sure why they did set cookie.test.

Comment: It does not make sense that the check is happening before the writing of the cookie. Specifically because when the check fails the request is aborted. You are not sharing actual code so it is hard to tell the exact problem. Generally speaking, the cookie will need to be set before you check for it. Is there code in Application.cfc (or Application.cfm) regarding cookies?

Comment: @Miguel-F I just found this line in Application.cfc <cfset THIS.SetClientCookies = true />.This cfcookie test is only defined on .cfm page. Nothing is set in Application.cfc related to cookie.test.

Comment: Any chance this is in a component(.cfc vs .cfm)? ... is there anyway that despite the <cfookie> being set at the bottom of the file, it is in a <cffunction> and thus possibly get run before the <cfif>?  (Have you tried setting the cookie manually and seeing what happens)?

Comment: @Hedge7707 when you say setting the cookie manually what do you mean by that exactly? Isn't example of cfcookie test above set manually? This code is in AppMenu.cfm file. I did not find anything in Application.cfc that is related to cfcookie test.

Comment: @espresso_coffee, I meant what if you set the cookie outside of the current ColdFusion logic... IE make a quick test page and set the cookie there. (If these were test servers (for a legacy application) , its very possible that the cookie was set for testing reasons a long while back and never cleared) and thus the logic just worked...does the code running on the production server have this same exact logic?

Comment: @Hedge7707 I have checked production server and on the same page they use the same logic. I still think this was just for testing purpose but I might be wrong. I tried to cfdump cookie variable after I login and there is no test element in the cookies. Also this worked on the CF10 but this morning we have switched to CF16.

Comment: @espresso_coffee  Do you guys use any Client variables? I know it is possible to store the client variable in cookies... but I have never tried to access them through the cookie scope? Any chance there is something like Client.test or something of that ilk floating around?

Comment: @Hedge7707 I have checked but there is no client.test so this might be some code that was used for developing purpose but never removed after that. The only weird fact is that same exact code is on production site.

Comment: I believe that `isDefined("Cookie.test")` may not see a difference between `<cfcookie name="test">` and `<cfset variables.cookie.test = 42` (or similar). Also CF2016 is a bit better than CF10 at how it scope-hunts (which may be why it's "woking" in 10. Try changing the code to use `structKeyExists(cookie,"Test")` or use Developer Tools in your browser to open the page and see if there is even a cookie there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isBoolean(URLSessionFormat("true"))` to check if cookies are enabled or not.

```
<cfif isBoolean(URLSessionFormat("true"))>
  cookies are enabled
<cfelse>
  cookies are not enabled
</cfif>
```

---

Also, I've created an UDF

https://cflib.org/udf/isCookiesEnabled

```
/**
 * Returns true if browser cookies are enabled.
 * 
 * @return Returns a boolean. 
 * @author Alex Baban  
 *  
 */
function isCookiesEnabled() {
    return IsBoolean(URLSessionFormat("True"));
}
```

`<cfoutput>#isCookiesEnabled()#</cfoutput>`

---

live demo:

```
<cfset result = IsBoolean(URLSessionFormat("True")) />
<cfdump var = "#result#" />
```

https://trycf.com/gist/2746d807170a0dc74e7349935320a78e/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: Please explain your down vote. This is a solution for the problem.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either. The OP intent doesn't seem to be to look for a specific cookie (which this UDF doesn't do), but to verify the behavior of having access to a cookie (which this UDF does do).

Comment: This UDF needs to be explained.  In accordance to the docs the function is passing the value "True" as the URL string of URLSessionFormat( urlString ) .

Comment: @AndreasRu right, this UDF works with a bit of a hack indeed. If the client browser does not take cookies, URLSessionFormat() will append required client identification information to its argument and return. With appended info, the returned string will make IsBoolean() to return false. If the client has cookies enabled, URLSessionFormat() will just return the argument, so if the argument is a ColdFusion boolean type the IsBoolean will return true. Indeed the value of the boolean argument does not matter, it can even be "false" or "0" and if the browser takes cookies the UDF will return true.

Comment: However, it's not possible to check if cookies are enabled in the browser with just onr single http  request, that's technically not possible, but that solution assumes it would suffice. That may only work after a second request (redirect, reload or similar) and is limited to having session or client management enabled for the application.

Comment: @AndreasRu yes, session or client management needs to be enabled. And, it works on every request, including the very first one. Try it.

Comment: @AlexBaban It's technically not possible to test for cookies within just one request. You always need at least two: one for setting the cookie in the server response, other for verifying it server side through the client request header. Please see https://dev.lucee.org/t/how-to-reliably-check-if-the-jsessionid-cookie-was-set-in-the-client-browser/9931/9?u=andreas

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because of a thread posted to the Lucee user forum.  Because it's cfml specific and not limited to ACF I'm posting an additional answer here.

**It's not possible to set and test for cookies within one request**, because cookies are set as a server response header and only then added to the clients request headers for all subsequently requests by the browser/client. In other words: The technique of using cookies always needs one request for setting the cookie and another for sending the cookie.

Also, I still can't understand how the above solution with *IsBoolean(URLSessionFormat("True"))* should be viable or work. According to cfdocs of [urlsessionformat](https://cfdocs.org/urlsessionformat) the function expects an URL string and not a boolean value as string and would return a string with the URL session token. In my opinion that code always returns true. Secondly, the UDF comment says it *'Returns true if browser cookies are enabled'* and that isn't possible within a single request.  This answer needs further elaboration.

Because there are many possible solutions, I'm just showing a simple alternative that shows visitors that cookies are en/disabled. It's basically a template (cookieset.cfm) that creates the cookie and subsequently loads a second template(cookiechecker.cfm) within an iframe. This alternative also doesn't need to have session management or client management of your cfml engine enabled.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cookie tester</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!--- set cookies so that these are submitted to the servers response headers --->
        <cfset cookieName="myCookieTest">
        <cfset cookieValue=hash(now())>
        <cfcookie name="#cookieName#" value="#cookieValue#">
        <cfoutput>
            <!--- embedded iframe that will send existent cookies the the iframe src template within the client request headers --->
            <iframe src="cookiecheck.cfm?cname=#urlencode(cookieName)#&cvalue=#urlencode(cookieValue)#" name="cookieFrame"></iframe>
        </cfoutput>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


<!--- cookiecheck.cfm --->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cookie Check</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <cfif structKeyExists( url, "cname" ) and structKeyExists( url, "cvalue" )> 
            <cfif structKeyExists(COOKIE, url.cname) and cookie[  url.cname ] is url.cvalue>
                Cookies activated!
            <cfelse>
                Cookies deactivated!
            </cfif>
        <cfelse>
            cookie data not specified in URL
        </cfif>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```